# How to Connect to MYSQL database in c# MVC website?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I currently run a PHP website which uses MYSQL for the database but now I what to move the website to MVC .Net environment but can't figure out how to this is what I am trying:

I Installed MYSQL.data.Entity, EF, and Web through Nuget package

then I added the connection string in the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;User Id=root;password=''"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Password is left empty because there is no password on the database as I running it locally to test it

after all that I still cant view the Database I Server Explorer? should I be able to view the database in server explorer?

How can I make it work?

(also note I took the live database and put it into local)

Comment: VS *usually* maps your connection string to one in Server Explorer. You can also try manually adding the connection string through Server Explorer > Data Connections, right-click > "Add Connection..." and try entering the details that way?

Answer (score 2):

You are not mentioning the mySql Connector for .NET. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Install it and it should start working ;)

Comment: Can I install that through Nuget package or is the only way to install it through the installer?

Comment: @user3689285 Install from the package manager I think, you will need to modify your web config though

Comment: Nope still cant connect to it, is it because I'm running MYSQL/phpmyadmin through WAMP? which I have started?

Comment: Try connecting using MySql Administrator. Can you get that working?